# IntelliJ Idea поиск в файле

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажие, жму ctrl + f в файле, появляется окно поиска. Однако поиск перестал что либо находить. Вне зависимости русский / английский.
Как с этим бороться?

Comment: проверьте выбранные чекбоксы рядом с полем ввода

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.